# Flutter local notification body not showing all notification text (flutter_local_notifications package)

Tags: flutter, dart, localnotification

I used `flutter_local_notifications: ^0.7.1+3` in my Flutter app to push schedule notifications. All is well in this but the problem in my notification body is that it shows just one line of text, and I can't expand or stretch notification to show all the notification body text.

This is my try:

```dart
class NotificationUtil {
  final notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  final int checkOutNotifyId = 0;

  NotificationUtil(BuildContext context) {
    final settingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_notify_icon');
    final settingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) =>
            onSelectNotification(context));
    notifications.initialize(
        InitializationSettings(settingsAndroid, settingsIOS),
        onSelectNotification: (context) async => onSelectNotification);
  }

  Future<void> showCheckOutNotify([int maximumCheckoutHours]) async {
    await notifications.periodicallyShow(
        checkOutNotifyId,
        AttendanceConstants.SCHEDULE_NOTIFICATION_TITLE,
        AttendanceConstants.SCHEDULE_NOTIFICATION_BODY +
            '$maximumCheckoutHours Hour/s of your attendance',
        RepeatInterval.Hourly,
        _ongoing);
  }

  NotificationDetails get _ongoing {
    final androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id',
      'your channel name',
      'your channel description',
      importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.High,
      ongoing: true,
    );
    final iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    return NotificationDetails(androidChannelSpecifics, iOSChannelSpecifics);
  }
```

Comment: I found the solution by adding **style** property: 
`style: AndroidNotificationStyle.BigText`

Comment: If you found the solution, how about creating your own answer? You can accept it after 48h.

Comment: Check out @ahmedel-shafei's solution in [his question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61179611/4756173).

Comment: What about when my app is closed completely. Talking of when notification is handled by android tray

Answer (score 54, accepted):

add [ BigTextStyleInformation('') ] in [ AndroidNotificationDetails() ]

```dart
NotificationDetails get _ongoing {
    final androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id',
      'your channel name',
      'your channel description',
      importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.High,
      ongoing: true,

      styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(''),
    );
```

Comment: What about when my app is closed completely. Talking of when notification is handled by android tray

Comment: did you find how to display all notification content in the tray? @b.john

Comment: I didn't, so I left the feature. But If you get a solution please share.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I tested it on Android Pie(Version 9).

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is here for the package awesome_notifications, use:

```
notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigText,
```

inside notification content.