# How to show more than one line in a notification message (flutter_local_notifications package)

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, ellipsis

I have a problem that only the first line in the notification body appears, how can I make the notification expanded with large content?

This is the code, using the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package:

```dart
void showNotification(int id, String title, String content, DateTime time) async {
  final AndroidNotificationDetails android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'ch_ID', 'Ch_Name', 'ch_Description', 
      priority: Priority.High, importance: Importance.Max);
  final IOSNotificationDetails ios = IOSNotificationDetails();
  final NotificationDetails platform = NotificationDetails(android, ios);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
      id,
      '$title',
      '$content',
      time,
      platform,
      payload: 'payload'
  );
}
```

[image: notification with cut text]

Comment: Please show the code you're using for the implementation of your notification. If you're using a simple `Text` widget, maybe specifying the max number of lines will provide more lines to the notification. Check out the [`maxLines`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/maxLines.html) parameter of the `Text` widget.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro
no it's not a widget, it's a string ....

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
         id,
        '$title',
        '$content',
        time,
        platform,
        payload: 'payload'
    );

Comment: Are you using the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package?

Comment: yes I'm using this package

Comment: [This other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57239754/4756173) has a similar issue. Have you tried the solution he mentions in the comment: set `style: AndroidNotificationStyle.BigText`?

Comment: okay finally I found the solution, your last comment helped me to get it.
thank you a lot for helping me.

Comment: It's all thanks to that guy in the other question.